# Fetch Api javascript receive JSON when error

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I post data to server using fetch:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'post'
  })
  .then(status)
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('error: ' + error);
  });
});
```

This is status method

```
const status = (res) => {
  console.log(res);
  if(res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300) {
    return Promise.resolve(res.json());
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(res.json());
  }
}
```

If code is 200 then it works fine (I receive my JSON). But when it is not, I catch the error and log it. It shows Unauthorized but I expect that I receive my error JSON. Something like this

```
{ 
 "status": 400,
 "error": "pass is not corret"
}
```

How can I catch my Json error?

Comment: What's the `fetch` made of?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch

Comment: are you saying that even for status HTTP, the body of the response will be JSON? your code should work as is in this case - please verify in the browser developer tools that the server is indeed sending valid JSON in the event of a 400 status

Comment: What exactly is the server returning? A 200 page with the status marked as 400 in the body?

Comment: Protip; console.log('error:', error); is an easier and better visual way to debug.

Comment: I expect that when I got error status HTTP, I still can receive my error JSON which contains error message. But the code above does not return me my error JSON

Comment: tip: `return Promise.resolve(res.json());` can be `return res.json();`

Comment: the console log show exactly like this when I got error: error: [object Promise] (it's a promise object)

Comment: instead of `return Promise.reject(res.json());` do `return res.json().then(v => Promise.reject(v));` - don't ask me why, but it works :p

Comment: Not work. I got a log: error: [object Object]

Comment: Are you sure the api is returning a status code header of 4xx and not returning 200, with a json object that has the key "status" with a value of 4xx?

Comment: Sure. I test with postman

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

At this point I'd think that you'd just need to return the JSON from the response. Judging by your conditional though you're returning the JSON regardless?:

```
const status = (res) => {
  console.log(res);
  if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300) {
    return res.json();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`res.json()` returns a `Promise`. When you call `Promise.reject` you can only pass it a reason for the rejection. Like a string, object or Error describing why you're rejecting.

I would change the code a bit to

```
const status = (res) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    res.json().then((json) => {
      if(res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300) {
        resolve(json);
      }
      else {
        reject(json)
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Source:

- [MDN - Promise.resolve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)
- [MDN - Promise.reject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject)